# Efficient binarization of a list

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, random

I am generating a list of 1's, 2's, and 3's with different probabilities for each number. I then convert this list into three binarized lists, giving a list of the locations of each digit in the original list. There must be a more efficient way to do this? Perhaps changing the way I make the original list?

```
list = RandomChoice[{0.5, 0.3, 0.2} -> {1, 2, 3}, 20]
list1 = ReplacePart[ReplacePart[ReplacePart[list, Position[list, 2] -> 0], 
   Position[list, 3] -> 0], Position[list, 1] -> 1]
list2 = ReplacePart[ReplacePart[ReplacePart[list, Position[list, 1] -> 0], 
   Position[list, 3] -> 0], Position[list, 2] -> 1]
list3 = ReplacePart[ReplacePart[ReplacePart[list, Position[list, 1] -> 0], 
   Position[list, 2] -> 0], Position[list, 3] -> 1]
```

Comment: Most answers assume one needs to generate `list` as the OP does, but he explicitly asks whether a different method of generation might be faster.  I think there is (see below).

Comment: Does "OP" stand for opening paragraph?

Comment: @Michael B. Heaney No, 'original poster' (the person who started the thread) or 'original post'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is very fast and avoids an intermediate step of creating 1s, 2s and 3s:

```
mylist = RandomChoice[{.3, .2, .5} -> {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, 300];
Transpose[mylist]
```

The generation of the list and the result is about twice as fast as the generation of the list and the result in the fastest method described by others here.

As @CarlWolf points out, using a `PackedArray` speeds things too:

```
Timing[mylist = 
   Developer`PackedArray[
   RandomChoice[{.3, .2, .5} -> {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, 
   10^8]];
 Transpose[mylist];]
```

{4.04332, Null}

Comment: For optimal efficiency with this method, you should include ``Developer`ToPackedArray`` in appropriate places. Otherwise it is far slower than the other packed array methods for large lists.

Comment: Yes... PackedArrays will help... just as they'll help a number of other proposed solutions.

Comment: I'm just pointing out that your statement that your answer is the fastest is not correct for long lists.

Comment: $10,000,000$ samples in 1.5 seconds should be fast enough for anyone, though.

Comment: It also helps to use the packed `IdentityMatrix[3]` instead of the unpacked `{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}`.

Comment: Hah!  I hadn't thought of that!  Thanks.  Hmmm... actually:  Just tried it:  it slowed everything down by a factor of nearly 2.  I don't think Packing such a small matrix helps.

Comment: That's because you used the nonexistent ``Developer`PackedArray`` symbol instead of ``Developer`ToPackedArray``.

Comment: I'm just surprised that the output of `RandomChoice` isn't a packed array by default...

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Good comment! I provided an answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/165441/45431)

Answer (score 10):

**Edit:**

@CarlWoll brought to my attention that `RandomChoice` may produce unpacked arrays. This is why I update the timings. Previously, I stated that Carls' solutiuon need ten times as long as the first proposal below. This is not true for `PackedArray`s. Mea culpa.

```
list = Developer`ToPackedArray[RandomChoice[{0.5, 0.3, 0.2} -> {1, 2, 3}, 200000]];
```

Another very efficient possibility is

```
RepeatedTiming[
 list1a = Subtract[1,Unitize[Subtract[list,1]]];
 list2a = Subtract[1,Unitize[Subtract[list,2]]];
 list3a = Subtract[1,Unitize[Subtract[list,3]]];
][[1]]
```

> 0.00069

This is still a bit faster than @Carl's proposal:

```
RepeatedTiming[
  list1b = Unitize@Clip[list, {1, 1}, {0, 0}];
  list2b = Unitize@Clip[list, {2, 2}, {0, 0}];
  list3b = Unitize@Clip[list, {3, 3}, {0, 0}];
  ][[1]]
```

> 0.00217

Other notable ways to do it:

Using `SparseArray` (not so efficient):

```
{list1c,list2c,list3c} = Normal[SparseArray[
 Transpose[{list,Range[Length[list]]}]->1,
 {3,Length[list]}
]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.082

Another nice way is

```
{list1d, list2d, list3d} = Transpose[IdentityMatrix[3][[list]]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.0032

Comment: Your `list` is unpacked, which is why `Clip` is slow.

Comment: @CarlWoll I am sorry! I updated the timings in the meantime...

Comment: My timings on OSX with M11.2 are much closer, with the `Clip` approach becoming faster with larger array sizes (e.g., 10^6 or 10^7).

Answer (score 8):

There are many possibilities, but I like using [`Clip`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clip):

```
Unitize@Clip[list,{1,1},{0,0}]
Unitize@Clip[list,{2,2},{0,0}]
Unitize@Clip[list,{3,3},{0,0}]
```

> {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}
>
> {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
>
> {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0}

**Addendum**

If your lists consist of just integers, than a compiled version is possible, e.g.:

```
fc = Last @ Compile[{{d, _Integer, 1}, {t,_Integer}},
    Table[Boole[Compile`GetElement[d, i]==2], {i, Length@d}],
    CompilationTarget->"C",
    RuntimeOptions->"Speed"
];
```

Comparison:

```
lst = Developer`ToPackedArray @ RandomChoice[{.5,.2,.3}->{1,2,3}, 10^7];

r1 = fc[lst, 2]; //RepeatedTiming
r2 = BitXor[1, Unitize @ BitXor[2, lst]]; //RepeatedTiming

r1 === r2
```

> {0.042, Null}
>
> {0.0614, Null}
>
> True

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** On Wolfram Cloud, the timing comparison I get is the opposite of David's claim  that *"the result is about twice as fast as the generation of the list and the result in the fastest method described by others here"*; that is, to my surprise,  `BitXor`-based method is more than 2x faster than David's method. Using `RandomVariate`+ `EmpiricalDistribution` + `WeightedData` combination instead of `RandomChoice`  improves the timings. Using `IdentityMatrix[3]` as suggested by @Carl, the timings for David's method improve significantly but they are still no better than the timings for `BitXor`-based methods.

```
ClearAll[f1,f2,f3,f4]
f1[n_]:= Module[{lst=Developer`ToPackedArray@RandomChoice[{0.5, 0.3, 0.2}->{1, 2, 3}, n]},
   BitXor[1, Unitize[BitXor[#, lst] & /@ {1, 2, 3}] ]]
f2[n_]:= Module[{lst=Developer`ToPackedArray[ RandomVariate[
   EmpiricalDistribution[WeightedData[Range[3], {.5, .3, .2}]], n]]},
  BitXor[1, Unitize[BitXor[#, lst] & /@ {1, 2, 3}] ]]
f3[n_]:= Transpose[Developer`ToPackedArray@RandomChoice[{.3, .2, .5} -> 
  {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, n]]
f4[n_]:= Transpose[Developer`ToPackedArray@RandomChoice[{.3, .2, .5} -> 
   IdentityMatrix[3], n]]

funcs = {f1, f2, f3, f4};
timings = Prepend[Table[Prepend[Table[First[RepeatedTiming[funcs[[j]][i]]], 
  {j, 1, 4}], i], {i, {200000, 10^6}}], {"n", "f1","f2","f3", "f4"}];
Grid[timings, Dividers -> All] // TeXForm
```

> $\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
> \hline
>  \text{n} & \text{f1} & \text{f2} & \text{f3} & \text{f4} \\
> \hline
>  200000 & 0.0069 & 0.0061 & 0.016 & 0.0063 \\
> \hline
>  1000000 & 0.0359 & 0.032 & 0.0885 & 0.035 \\
> \hline
> \end{array}$

(I cannot time larger lists because the required computation exceeds the memory limit of the free cloud accounts.)

---

**Original answer:**

```
{l1, l2, l3} = BitXor[1, Unitize[BitXor[#, list] & /@ {1, 2, 3}] ]

TeXForm @ {list, l1, l2, l3}
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccccc}
>  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 2 \\
>  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

**Timings:** Using Henrik's setup, this is twice as fast as Henrik's method.

```
list = Developer`ToPackedArray[RandomChoice[{0.5, 0.3, 0.2} -> {1, 2, 3}, 200000]];

RepeatedTiming[{l1, l2, l3} = BitXor[1, Unitize[BitXor[#, list] & /@ {1, 2, 3}] ]][[1]]
```

> 0.0013

```
RepeatedTiming[list1a = Subtract[1, Unitize[Subtract[list, 1]]];
  list2a = Subtract[1, Unitize[Subtract[list, 2]]];
  list3a = Subtract[1, Unitize[Subtract[list, 3]]];][[1]]
```

> 0.0025

```
RepeatedTiming[list1b = Unitize@Clip[list, {1, 1}, {0, 0}];
  list2b = Unitize@Clip[list, {2, 2}, {0, 0}];
  list3b = Unitize@Clip[list, {3, 3}, {0, 0}];][[1]]
```

> 0.0027

```
And @@ (Equal @@@ 
  Transpose[{{list1a, list2a,  list3a}, {list1b, list2b,  list3b}, {l1, l2, l3}}])
```

> True

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment to @DavidGStork's answer, using `IdentityMatrix[3]` instead of `{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}` improves the speed of his answer significantly.

Comment: @Carl, thank you. Was about to post the timing for that version.

Answer (score 3):

Using `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) and delayed rules for pattern matching, this can be done much more directly:

```
l1 = list /. (x_?NumericQ :> If[x == 1, 1, 0])
l2 = list /. (x_?NumericQ :> If[x == 2, 1, 0])
l3 = list /. (x_?NumericQ :> If[x == 3, 1, 0])
```

The `?NumericQ` is primarily there to avoid catching `List` in the replacement as well.

You could also map a suitable replacement function over the list:

```
l1 = If[# == 1, 1, 0] & /@ list
l2 = If[# == 2, 1, 0] & /@ list
l3 = If[# == 3, 1, 0] & /@ list
```

Answer (score 3):

```
list1e = Boole[# == 1] & /@ list;
list2e = Boole[# == 2] & /@ list;
list3e = Boole[# == 3] & /@ list;
```

another option is using Piecewise. For example:

```
fun[x_] := Piecewise[{{1, x == 1}}, 0]
SetAttributes[fun, Listable]
list1c = fun[list];
```

or the combination Reap/Scan:

```
list1d = Reap[Scan[If[# == 1, Sow[1], Sow[0]] &, list]][[2, 1]];
```