# RandomChoice output isn't packed

Tags: random, packed-arrays

Why isn't the output of RandomChoice a packed array? For instance:

```
RandomChoice[{.5, .2, .3} -> {1, 2, 3}, 10]
Developer`PackedArrayQ @ %
```

> {1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3}
>
> False

Answer (score 17):

In order for [`RandomChoice`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomChoice) to produce a packed array, the RHS of the rule needs to be packed:

```
pQ = Developer`PackedArrayQ;
pack = Developer`ToPackedArray;

pQ @ RandomChoice[pack[{.5, .2, .3}] -> pack[{1, 2, 3}], 10]
pQ @ RandomChoice[pack[{.5, .2, .3}] -> {1, 2, 3}, 10]
pQ @ RandomChoice[{.5, .2, .3} -> pack[{1, 2, 3}], 10]
```

> True
>
> False
>
> True

Comment: applies to `RandomSample` as well